# AWS RDS- Lock:transactionid vs Lock:tuple difference?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was checking the documentation for AWS RDS (along with the performance insights for my DB) and I saw that [lock:transactionid](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/apg-waits.locktransactionid.html) and [lock:tuple](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/apg-waits.locktuple.html) have 2 separate descriptions. However it's not clear to me what the difference is because rows and tuples mean the same thing in the DB. So why does RDS have 2 separate ways to describe the same thing?